# Best/fastest way to select items from generic list that connect with offset mins

Tags: c#, linq, list, generics

I have a list of object with StartTime and EndTime.

I want to select all items that starts in given date and all that "connects" with minutes given from end time. There should not be any overlapping times, because I have checked those earlier.

F.e. Class

```
public class tObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

So if i have tObject with these kind of start & end times :

```
ID = 1 StartTime  = 21.1.2016 21:00 - EndTime = 22.1.2016 01:00
ID = 2 StartTime  = 22.1.2016 01:30 - EndTime = 22.1.2016 05:00
ID = 3 StartTime  = 22.1.2016 06:00 - EndTime = 22.1.2016 07:00
ID = 4 StartTime  = 22.1.2016 07:50 - EndTime = 22.1.2016 08:00
ID = 5 StartTime  = 22.1.2016 09:10 - EndTime = 22.1.2016 11:00
```

How can I select from ListItems that also 2,3,4 ID:s (those connects with 60 mins offset) will be selected to listTodaysItems ?

```
int iMinutes = 60;
List<tObject> listTodaysItems = listItems.Where(r => r.StartTime.Date == dtGivenDate.Date).ToList();
```

I know this is possible to do with for -loop but I'll have to do this often so I'll prefer single line select if it's possible. Also want to know if its possible to check other values in same list somehow.

So what is my best/fastest option here ?

Comment: So basically you have a threshold `maxOffset` and want to select each entry which's StartTime is at maximum `maxOffset` away from any other entrie's EndTime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you right, you need the following:

```
int threshold = 20;             
var withinThreshold = 
  list.Where(x => list.Where(y => y.StartTime < x.StartTime && y.EndTime.AddMinutes(threshold) > x.StartTime)
                      .Any())
      .Select(x => x).ToList();
```

This looks at every entry that started before the current one and checks if the current one is inside the threshold-range to any of those entries.

Here some full example program with test data, ready-to-go:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class TObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<TObject> list = new List<TObject>();

        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            list.Add(new TObject());
            list[i].StartTime = (i == 0 ? DateTime.Now : list[i-1].EndTime.AddMinutes(i + 1));
            list[i].EndTime = list[i].StartTime.AddMinutes(i);
            Console.WriteLine(list[i].StartTime + " - " + list[i].EndTime);
        }

        int threshold = 20;

        var withinThreshold = 
        list.TakeWhile( // Stop as soon as the an entry does not match the condition
            x => 
                !list.Where(y => y.StartTime < x.StartTime).Any() || // First entry
                list.Where(y => y.StartTime < x.StartTime && y.EndTime.AddMinutes(threshold) > x.StartTime).Any()) // Following entries withing threshold
        .Select(x => x)
        .ToList();

        Console.WriteLine("Within threshold: ");
        withinThreshold.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.StartTime + " - " + x.EndTime));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your post.

There's only onething missing. If there is a 60+ mins gap somewhere, this way it still graps items after that with the same rule.

fe. times  21:00-01:00,  01:30-03:00 (this is earlier than my first example), 06:00-07:00,  07:50-08:00,  09:10-11:00

In this example It should not take anything after 01:30-03:00 timerange befause after that there is 60+ mins gap before next one

Comment: Hm, that's what my comment was about. I will think about it, i will write back.

Comment: What you are looking for is TakeWhile, I will update my answer, then it should be finished and able to accept.

Comment: So, as you can see I updated the code to use TakeWhile and now also the first entry is grabbed (was not included in the old version). Is it correct now?

Comment: I got it working now with your code. There was minor change because I use it in another loop, but anyways it's working nice now. Thanks!